# What is the state of the art in efficient boolean function operations?

Tags: reference-request, boolean-algebra

How do you most efficiently combine boolean functions with a large number of variables using AND, OR, and NOT?  The most up-to-date work that I can find on this subject is about 20 years old ([Efficient data structures for Boolean functions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9590790R#)).  Which search terms should I be using to explore this question?

Edit:

I am starting from about 200 simple boolean functions.  These are combined with each other using AND, OR, NOT, and XOR to give other boolean functions, which are then also combined using AND, OR, NOT, and XOR.  The process repeats about 3000 times, until a final combination gives me a single boolean expression.  I'm interested in that final expression.

Representing the functions as DNF or CNF makes certain operations (NOT and XOR) slow.  Representing the functions as ROBDDs is an option - are there any drawbacks here?  I'm not sure whether SMT solvers are useful here, because I am interested in the final equation rather than whether the equation is satisfiable.  What else should I be looking at?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently combining"? Also, this seems quite broad. Community, your votes?

Comment: Is it possible that by "combine" you mean reduce, simplify, or the like? That is, are you trying to turn $f(a, b) = a + ab$ into $f(a, b) = a$? Or is what you're asking about efficiently evaluating expressions - i.e., determining the value of $a + ab$ is $T$ if $a$ is (without evaluating $ab$)?

Comment: I mean that if I have two boolean expressions, $f(a,b,..,z)$ and $g(a,b,..,z)$, which algorithms should I look at to be able to figure out what $f(...)$ OP $g(...)$ is, where OP is AND or OR? Ideally in a reduced form, since the resulting expression will likely be the input to another expression.

Comment: I think you are asking about something like: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Boolean_functions,_minimization_of

Comment: And also this: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BooleanMinimize.html

Comment: Or maybe this?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram

Comment: In particular the reference to Knuth vol 4, which should bring you up to the state of the art as of 5 or 10 years ago.

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking.  It would help if you edited your question to specify your problem as follows: tell us what the inputs are, tell us what the outputs are, and give us an example of an instance of the problem (an example set of inputs, and show us what the correct output would be).  Also, make sure to tell us what research you've done on your own, and to check out the references other have given you.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  However, it is still unclear what operations you want to perform on these expressions/functions.  Do you want to test for satisfiability?  Test two functions to see if they are the same function?  Put them into a canonical form?  What's a typical number of variables and clauses?  And, what research have you done, and what have you tried?  BDDs are the obvious starting place.

Comment: try also ZDDS of interest to knuth. is this for an academic project or some application? sounds interesting try [chat] also. disagree with comments that the question is too vague. there are a bunch of basic/standard operations on binary sets which are studied & the question doesnt need to narrow on in on specific ones to be relevant/useful for the site.

Comment: This post needs to be edited to make question more clear and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious method is to use [BDDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram).

Given a BDD for two boolean functions $f,g$, you can form a BDD for $f \land g$, $f \lor g$, $\neg f$, $f \implies g$, $f \oplus g$ (xor), and many other binary operations on them.  Also, given BDDs for $f,g$, you can test whether $f$ and $g$ are the same boolean function.

The worst-case behavior is that their size might grow to be exponential in $n$, the number of boolean variables, but empirically, the size often remains manageable in many real-world applications, e.g., when there is suitable structure in the underlying boolean functions.  In the model-checking world, designs with 50-200 boolean variables are routinely handled using BDDs.

It's also possible to manipulate boolean expressions in symbolic form, and then use SAT solvers or SMT solvers to test for equivalence.  This is another plausible alternative.

My advice is: try BDDs first, then if they don't scale well enough for your needs, you can try SAT-based solutions.  If that still doesn't work, come back to ask for more suggestions (providing more details about your specific setting and what you've tried).

Answer (score 0):

try also [ZDDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-suppressed_decision_diagram) (Zero-suppressed Decision Diagrams) for "sparse" functions where most evaluations are zero and subject to more recent research. [Knuth](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~katayanagi/2009/knuth_abstract.html) has researched/implemented them and regards them highly, and compressions can be dramatically better in some applications. see also Minato for a [survey](http://www.jst.go.jp/sicp/ws2010_austria/presentation/presentation_22.pdf)/ contrast with BDDs & a database application.